# Identify this plant in a woodlands setting?

Tags: identification, woodland

[image]

A very short plant growing along the edge of a Zone 8 forest. They're growing in a groundcover type formation. The area is very shady.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a Fan Clubmoss. https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=lydi3

Comment: That seems to be it. Wow, thanks! :)